# Is there a graphical way of enabling scroll lock on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard

I know there's a graphical way on Ubuntu, [as seen here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=931827&p=5867882#post5867882).

Comment: Couldn't find the graphical way. On command line you can run 'xmodmap -pm' to see your modifiers and run 'xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'' to bind it to mod3. As seen here http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/puppy-71/scroll-lock-doesn%27t-work-536178/#post2665131

Comment: So, did you solve it then? If so, please post an answer explaining how you did it as it might be helpful for others in a similar situation :)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a GUI way so here's the command line version:

Run `xmodmap -pm` to see your modifiers

Run `xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'`to bind it to mod3

Answer found from here http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/puppy-71/scroll-lock-doesn%27t-work-536178/#post2665131